# Firefox on windows 8 shows a Bing toolbar when new tab is requested

Tags: firefox, bing

Firefox 19.0.2 suddenly opens a new tab with a Bing toolbar rather than the page with small pictures of one's favorite websites. I just want to stop this happening. What is Microsoft  up to?

Answer (score 1):

Check `Tools`: `Add-ons`: `Extensions` for an extension called "**Default Tab**." Disabling it will solve your problem.